# How to recover the Ajax extension tab in visual studio 2008 sp1 toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit

hi all i accidentally deleted ajax extension tab in toolkit in the belief that it is ajax control toolkit tab. Can u please help me to recover the old ajax extension tab in the toolbox ? i tried resetting the toolbox ,it worked but there are a lot of controls repeating
in the ajax extension pane so i deleted it again. Each time i try to recover it the same controls repeats. Any workarounds for this issue? i need only one set of items in the ajax extension tab. please help ..